# Entity framework, Navigation Properties, call and store values in the database table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, parsing

I am trying to parse a text file into 3 tables using C Sharp and T-SQL. Below are the table definitions - 
 1) TTransaction (TransactionID Identity(1,1), some other attributes) 
 2) TMatch       (MatchID Identity(1,1), some other attributes)
 3) TTransactionXTMatch (TransactionID ,MatchID )

Using C sharp, I parsed the data into tables TTransaction and TMatch. I am not sure how to use the navigation properties of Entity Framework to populate these 2 ID's in the TTransactionXTMatch (Bridge) Table. There is one to many relationship between TTransaction and TMatch.
See the code below:

```
 TTransaction txn = new TTransaction();

                        txn.TRN = txnNo;
                        txn.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Amount);
                        txn.TransactionText = Convert.ToString(txnText);
                        txn.TransactionLocation = TxnLOC;

                        context.TTransactions.Add(txn); 
                        context.SaveChanges();

 TMatch Mtc = new TMatch();

                        Mtc.RiskWord = RiskWord;
                        Mtc.GoodGuyWord = GoodGuyWord;
                        Mtc.Origin = Origin;
                        Mtc.Location = Location;

                        context.TMatches.Add(Mtc); //Adding to the database
                        context.SaveChanges();
```

I am wondering how do call the TTransactionXTMatch table since it doesn't come up in the model and there is no class created for it. It does show in the navigation properties but I am not sure how to use that.
Can someone please shed some light on this. Kindly let me know if you need additional info on what I am doing.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Code first sample for you. In this sample note that, there is a bunch of Customers created first, then a bunch of products (real world would look like that). 
Then to show Many-To-Many, we add random number of products to a customer through Products property (navigation property) in a loop and EF does the rest.

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=CodeFirstDbSample;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    CreateSampleCodeFirstData();
    ListData();
}

private void CreateSampleCodeFirstData()
{
    var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var c = new Customer { CustomerName="c" + i };
    ctx.Customers.Add( c );
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var p = new Product { ProductName="p" + i };
    ctx.Products.Add( p );
  }

  ctx.SaveChanges();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var customer = ctx.Customers.Single (c => c.CustomerName == "c"+i);
    var products = ctx.Products.OrderBy (p => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
    customer.Products = new List<Product>();
    customer.Products.AddRange( products );
  }

  ctx.SaveChanges();
}

private void ListData()
{
  var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);
  Console.WriteLine ("By Customer");
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'-'));
  foreach (Customer c in ctx.Customers.Include("Products"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName);
    Console.WriteLine ("\t\t{0}", 
      string.Join(",", c.Products.Select (p => p.ProductName)));
  }
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'='));
  Console.WriteLine ();

  Console.WriteLine ("By Product");
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'-'));
  foreach (Product p in ctx.Products.Include("Customers"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", p.ProductId, p.ProductName);
    Console.WriteLine ("\t\t{0}", 
       string.Join(",", p.Customers.Select (c => c.CustomerName) ));
  }
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'='));
  Console.WriteLine ();
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(string connectionString)
     : base(connectionString)  {}
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IS your project using code first or database first migrations?
It is possible that the table was created without a migration meaning that Entity Framework would not work with this table.